# Looking for a TV Series from 2006-2010

Tags: story-identification, tv, androids

There was a series during 2006-2010 with a woman android. She had her [fringe cut above her eyes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsimC.jpg) and the rest of the hair was long. She was brunette too. The graphics in the series had an [odd orange colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTdzi.jpg) which I saw in a game called "Deus Ex : Human Revolution" . It was very futuristic-style graphics. I was too young back then and I do not recall the name.  I've tried to contact the channel which it was played on in my homecountry but they have kept no records.

The plot was like the following: she was programmed and built but later in the series she fell in love with a human and there was a debate because she was a robot. I don't recall much but I do remember what her face looked like.

The series came out when Dexter came out too, so this is a clue.

The channel which this series was played on is called SKAI in Greece.

Comment: Was this an animated series, or live action? If animated, did it match a particular animation style (for instance, manga)? Also - you might try to locate any magazines that published television schedules during that time (in the US, we have *TV Guide*), or check the library for old newspapers from when it was on (again, in the US, most daily newspapers publish the local TV schedule for the day).

Comment: It was live action. I have looked up on Magazines and forums and I couldn't find the series .

Comment: Do you know where the TV show was from originally? E.g. was it a US show, European, Japanese?

Comment: Browsing through IMDB I came upon _[Dark Angel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0204993/?ref_=tt_rec_tt)_, of which the poster has the kind of orange glow you talk about. It's about genetically engineered people rather than androids though.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take an even wilder guess. In the 90's there was a cancelled show from Argentina, based on a comic book called CyberSix. This is the protagonist:

[image: Cybersix]

According to [the wiki](http://cybersix.wikia.com/wiki/Live-Action_Series) it was transmitted in Russia, I wouldn't be surprised if it was sold quietly to some other channels elsewhere around the world.

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbArxQDGNUA) you can see the protagonist fighting, and a little bit of that orange tinted aesthetics. Unfortunately it seems the produced chapters are lost.

Comment: The question says 2006-2010, why do you think your 90s TV series is the one?

Comment: Because it could have been broadcasted later?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't an attack, was just wondering.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't take it as such. Sorry if I sounded defensive :P

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, but "[Terminator - the Sarah Conner Chronicles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0851851/)"?

There is at least a brunette robot with long hair and the time frame (2008-2009) matches.

[image]

I never watched it so I don't know about the orange glow or the plot details.

Comment: Good guess, I immediately thought that too. But there wasn't really an "orange glow", or at least not one that stood out.